# Highcharts series zone not working with UTC date value in x axis

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, highcharts

I am trying to connect points across null point with dashed line in highstock line series graph.

I was able to get it work for non-date values for x values in data array. [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/devnigel/fds34zxa/).

However, when the x values of data array is UTC date value, series zone is not working as expected. [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/devnigel/w2kovymj/)

Just as I wrote this question, I realised that the issue here is with traversing the multidimensional array in buildZones function.

How can I fix this?

```
$(function() {

var data1 = [[1505715244000,84],[1505792275000,96],[1507004151000,105],[1507004493000,null],[1507004824000,null],[1507004912000,101],[1507180353000,90],[1507261620000,109],[1507262417000,100]]


 var seriesdata = [{type: 'spline', name: "ABC", data: data1,zones: null,connectNulls: true,zoneAxis: 'x', yAxis: 0,

                    showInLegend: false
                };

                seriesdata[0].zones=buildZones(data1);

  function buildZones(data) {
    var zones = [],
        i = -1, len = data.length, current, previous, dashStyle, value;

    while (data[++i][1] === null);
    zones.push({
      value: i
    });

    while (++i < len) {
      previous = data[i - 1][1];
      current = data[i][1];
      dashStyle = '';

      if (previous !== null && current === null) {
        dashStyle = 'solid';
        value = i - 1;
      } else if (previous === null && current !== null) {
        dashStyle = 'dot';
        value = i;
      }

      if (dashStyle) {
        zones.push({
          dashStyle: dashStyle,
          value: value
        });
      }
    }
    console.log(zones)
    return zones;
  }


  var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

   /* chart: {
      defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
      renderTo: 'container'
    },*/


    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        marker: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    },
    series: [seriesdata[0]]

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I just needed to change pushed value

```
function buildZones(data) {
var zones = [],
    i = -1, len = data.length, current, previous, dashStyle, value;

while (data[++i][1] === null);
zones.push({
  value:data[i][0]
});

while (++i < len) {
  previous = data[i - 1][1];
  current = data[i][1];
  dashStyle = '';

  if (previous !== null && current === null) {
    dashStyle = 'solid';
    value = data[i - 1][0];
  } else if (previous === null && current !== null) {
    dashStyle = 'dot';
    value = data[i][0];
  }

  if (dashStyle) {
    zones.push({
      dashStyle: dashStyle,
      value: value
    });
  }
}
console.log(zones)
return zones;
```

}

Comment: It is nice if you share specifically what you did, that way people do not have to comb through the code to figure it out.